# Get list view's scroll position

Tags: android

How would I go about retrieving a list view's scroll position? I am trying to get it to "round" or "snap" to items on the list so there isn't one half displayed at the top. I can make it move with setSelectionFromTop, but I can't find anyway to get the ListView's position.

Also is there a way to use SetSelectionFromTop like smoothScroll? I'd like to not have a sharp change when it adjusts the scroll.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, did you try smoothScrollByOffset and/or smoothScrollToPosition ?